# Use Javascript to Read Client CSV into Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, csv, file-upload

I know this looks like a duplicate question, but scouring similar topics has left me still clueless.  I'm trying to build an online character sheet for an RPG game where character stats are saved as a txt or csv file on the client's computer.

For example, the client may have a file saved titled `Grandulf.txt` which has a single line of content of all the relevant stats of that character as like this:

```
Grandulf,1,5,staff
```

except much longer which might give me a name, the character's strength stat, the character's wisdom stat, the character's weapon, etc.

I'd like the client (the person accessing my little web app) to be able to hit a button to upload any specific character file they have created which will then put the data into an array that I can use piece by piece throughout the web ap.

I think I can use `<input type="file" onchange="functionCSVtoArray();">` to start the process off, but I don't know how to get it into an array called `charStats` that I can use later.  For example, I will set a text field value equal to `charStats[0]` for the name since that will always be first, set a number field value to `charStats[1]` for the strength since I'll always have that be the second value in the array, and so forth.

I have (or will have) an html character sheet that people could just type in values each time, but I'm looking for a quick and simple way for people to "save" and "load" their characters without having to learn SQL, PHP, or other databasing acronyms that are beyond my ability and skill.

Is this possible?

EDIT: I tried this after I asked the original question, but I'm still not sure why it works.  In particular, I don't get why there is an "e" as the passed argument in the function.

```
loadCharacter.onchange = function(e) {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function(event) {
        charStats.value = event.target.result;
        statsArray = event.target.result;
        statsArray = statsArray.split(",");
        saveButton.disabled = false;
    }
    name = e.target.files[0].name;
    reader.readAsText(new Blob([e.target.files[0]], {
        "type": "text/plain"
    }));
    /* Need to take the statsArray and put everything in the appropriate fields on the character sheet */
}
```

Comment: While I understand where you're coming from with your comment, you happen to be incorrect in this case.  I'm not looking for someone to code for me but rather to understand how it works.  I didn't post any code since the previous 3+ hours were spent looking at different variations of code that I didn't understand.  I was unaware of the FileReader idea as posted below and am still learning how it works.  Thanks for looking all the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `FileReader`, `FileReader.prototype.readAsText()`

```
var charStats = [];
var reader = new FileReader;
reader.onload = function() {
  charStats.push(reader.result);
  // do stuff with `charStats` array here
  // as handler of `load` event of `FileReader` 
  // returns results asynchronously
}

functionCSVtoArray() {
  var file = document.querySelector("input[type=file]").files[0];
  reader.readAsText(file);
};
```

Comment: Thanks for the response!  Above is what I came up with in the meantime, but it looks like you have a better solution.

Comment: @ericbright2002 It is not necessary to pass `File` to `Blob` constructor, `File` object  inherits from `Blob` object